# Select first element which is placed after another element but not immediately

Tags: css, css-selectors

How is it possible to select **only the first element** (e.g. h2) after another element (e.g. h1) but which is **not necessarily placed immediately after** ? 
 So, element+element (e.g. h1 + h2) does not work because it selects elements that are placed **immediately** after elements

```
<h1> Title1 </h1>
..... <--! many tags but h2 -->
<h2> h2 Title2 selected </h2>
..... <--! many tags but h1 and h2-->
<h2> h2 Title3 not selected </h2>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now it's possible with one selector:

```css
h1:first-of-type ~ h2:not(h1:first-of-type ~ h2 ~ h2) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>h2 Title3 not selected </h2>
  <h1> Title1 </h1>
  <p>text</p>
  <h2> h2 Title2 selected </h2>
  <h3>text</h3>
  <h2> h2 Title3 not selected </h2>
</div>
```

---

**Old Answer**

I don't think you can achieve this with one selector, so you can try something like below:

```css
h1:first-of-type ~ h2 {
  color:red;
}
h1:first-of-type ~ h2 ~ h2 {
  color:initial; /*we reset the style for the others*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>h2 Title3 not selected </h2>
  <h1> Title1 </h1>
  <p>text</p>
  <h2> h2 Title2 selected </h2>
  <h3>text</h3>
  <h2> h2 Title3 not selected </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you think, it will be possible to write in CSS4 : `h1:first-of-type ~ h2 :not (h1:first-of-type ~ h2 ~ h2) { color:red;}`

Comment: @Stef1611 honestly I cannot tell you if yes or no we can do this. I am still not used to the advanced selector that will get introduced in the level 4

Comment: I do not know if you are interested but as you answered me, I send you this information. It  works in CSS4 but you have to remove the spaces before and after `:not. Everything is explained here :`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54115629/css4-selectors-and-browser

Comment: @Stef1611 oh yes of course, I thought the space was a simple typo of you doing a copy past, but yes the space need to get removed ... But what I meant is that since it still under draft we cannot be sure it will always work as the spec may change. it happened a lot of time where some selector used to work under draft then they disappear.

Comment: Thanks again for your first answer because, as I am new in CSS, it  triggered my curiosity (as I wrote in the other question). And I found very funny to use last version of CSS in minibrowser. I was not aware that there was only three engines (chromium, webkit and firefox) and it explains me many things. And it is only the beginning.

Comment: @Stef1611 if you are still interested, the selector you mention is now valid. The :not() with complex selector has a good support now