# CSS4 Selectors and browser

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to test (reason : just curiosity) CSS4 selectors and particularly the CSS pseudo-class :not() with a selector list (cf. code and [Select first element which is placed after another element but not immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894673/select-first-element-which-is-placed-after-another-element-but-not-immediately)). Is there a beta version of a browser to do that (OS : windows or Linux) or should I wait quietly ?

```
h1:first-of-type ~ h2 :not (h1:first-of-type ~ h2 ~ h2) { color:red;}
```

Comment: As Safari supports it i would guess that the [Linux WebKit](https://webkit.org/downloads/) version also does. But as there are only three engines  (if you ignore edge that switches to chromium), chromium, webkit and firefox, it would be faster if you download their dev builds and test it.

Comment: Thank you verify much. You give me a good idea. I googled "webkit recent build windows" and I followed the explanation found on this link https://medium.com/@alSkachkov/how-to-load-the-latest-webkit-on-windows-962a9219c1e1. Thus, I could test a recent version of webkit and this css pseudo class `h1:first-of-type ~ h2:not(h1:first-of-type ~ h2 ~ h2) { color:red;}` works perfectly. I think you could change your comment to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome 'Canary' is the Beta version of Chrome (for Developers)

https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/

Comment: This solution does work. But it is still working with the solution I wrote in my comment posted on Jan 10. I have just tested it in MiniBrowser (https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/archives.webkit.org/win-x86_64-release/242297.zip).